# Epsilon numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal number and define $f_\alpha$ as:

- $f_\alpha(0) = \alpha + 1$
- $f_\alpha(n+1) = \omega^{f_a(n)}$

Let $S(\alpha) = \sup\{f_a(n)\ |\ n \in \omega\}$

Then $S(\alpha)$ is an epsilon number and is the least epsilon number greater than $\alpha$.

Since none of natural numbers are epsilon number, I think $S(n)=S(m)$ for every natural numbers $n,m$. I know that I'm wrong but I don't know why. Please, help.

And I have problem with showing that $m<n\implies S(m)<S(n)$

Comment: Actually, $S(n)=S(m)$ for all natural numbers $n,m$. Since $\epsilon_0$ is the minimal epsilon number above of them.

Comment: Then how come my book says 'for every ordinal number $\alpha & \beta$ , if $\alpha < \beta$ then S($\alpha$) < S($\beta$)?

Comment: Your book probably has lots of typos, white lies, and full blown errors. It is the nature of books. If $\gamma$ is an epsilon number and $\gamma\le\alpha<\beta<S(\gamma)$, then $S(\alpha)=S(\beta)=S(\gamma)$, so you cannot prove the inequality you are asking.

Comment: Then how can i prove that there exists an isomorphism between 'class of ordinals' and 'class of epsilon numbers'? Or is it false too?

Comment: Oh, that's true. You know that, for any $\alpha$, $S(\alpha)>\alpha$ and $S(\alpha)$ is epsilon. So, you can enumerate the epsilons in increasing order: $\epsilon_0=S(0)$. Given $\epsilon_\alpha$, let $\epsilon_{\alpha+1}=S(\epsilon_\alpha)$. And for limit $\lambda$, let $\epsilon_\lambda=\sup\{\epsilon_\alpha\mid\alpha<\lambda\}$. You need to check: 1. Every $\epsilon_\alpha$ is an epsilon. This is clear except if $\alpha$ is limit. 2. Every epsilon is an $\epsilon_\alpha$. This can be proved by considering a least putative counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question was answered in comments and we [don't like leaving questions unanswered](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/what-should-one-do-when-ones-question-has-been-answered-in-the-comments), I'm adding [azarel's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153544/epsilon-numbers#comment353889_153544) as a CW answer:

Actually, $S(n)=S(m)$ for all natural numbers $n,m$. Since $\epsilon_0$ is the minimal epsilon number above of them.